# Python loop doesn't update variable?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to make a loop that turn a function (like f(x)=(2x+3)(2x-3)) into a better format for editing, simply by adding a '+' before numbers (it would become f(x)=(**+**2x+3)(**+**2x-3)). The problem is that in the loop, after I insert a new **char** in the middle of the string, the string doesn't update, so when the loop goes on and I try to access a certain index of the function string, the char isn't correct.

```
def rewriteFunction(function):
    for i, c in enumerate(function):
        newFunction += c
        if(str(c).isdigit()):
            if not(i == 0):
                if not(Sign.isSign(function[i - 1])):
                    function = function[:i] + "+" + function[i:]
```

If possible, could you answer me by sending the exact (corrected) code, without modifying it too much, of course if that's the right method to do that. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you have to _return_ function. Parameter won't be updated from caller's view because strings are immutable.

Comment: Yes, and  `enumerate()` operates on the original `function`, and never sees the udpates.

Comment: and if it saw the updates it would be wrong as well. Don't change object when iterating on it.

Comment: you mean like a recursive function?

Comment: Where is `newFunction` defined? That code should raise an `UnboundLocalError`...

Comment: This would be more simply solved with a regular expression: `re.sub(r'(?<![-+])\b(\d+)', r'+\1', function)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I don't think the OP wanted to split `33` into `3+3`, that is probably just a bug in their code.

Comment: Another way: `def rewriteFunction(function): return re.sub(r'(?<!\+|-)\b(\d+)', r'+\1', function)`. Adds a `+` in front of any group of numbers not preceded by `+` or `-`.  Examples: `'x+3'` => `'x+3'`, `'x-3'` => `'x-3'`, `'2x-3'` => `'+2x-3'`, `'x-33'` => `'x-33'`, `'3*2x'` => `'+3*+2x'`

Comment: For the fun of it, another way `''.join(('+' if s not in '0123456789+-' and t.isdigit() else '') + t for s, t in zip(' '+func, func))`.

Answer (score 1):

- In one line you store your updated data in the variable `newFunction`, but in another you store your updates back into `function`. For consistency, let's never change `function` and apply all of our updates to `newFunction`.
- You never initialize `newFunction`.
- You never explicitly return anything from `rewriteFunction()`.

Try this:

```
def rewriteFunction(function):
    newFunction = ''
    for i, c in enumerate(function):
        if(str(c).isdigit()):
            if not(i == 0):
                if not(function[i - 1] in '+-'):
                    newFunction += '+'
        newFunction += c
    return newFunction

assert rewriteFunction('f(x)=(2x+3)(2x-3)') == 'f(x)=(+2x+3)(+2x-3)'
```

Comment: With OP's algorithm double digit coefficients are a problem.  `f(x)=33x` => `f(x)=+3+3x`.

Comment: Thank you very much!! One last question: how can I equal "function" to the "new function" (note that I made a little change by defining both function and new function as lists), I mean, can you equal two lists?

Answer (score 1):

If your solutions isn't bound to using loops, you may give a try to [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to simplify things:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'f(x)=(2x+3)(2x-3))'
>>> re.sub(r'\b(?<![+-])(\d+)', r'+\1', s)
'f(x)=(+2x+3)(+2x-3))'
```

Feel free to ask any questions about the solution.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake. Thank you!